# Ruby - XXhash checksum large files

Tags: ruby

I have a 3GB file and I need to take a checksum of it using the ruby [xxhash](https://github.com/nashby/xxhash) library.  The problem I get an out of memory error.

Here is the code which causes the error:

```
contents = File.read('some_file')
checksum = XXhash.xxh64(contents, 123918230912)
```

I know libraries such as `openssl` and `digest/sha1` have update methods like so:

```
checksum = File.open('some_file', "rb") do |io|
  dig = Digest::SHA1.new
  buf = ""
  dig.update(buf) while io.read(4096, buf)
  dig
end
```

But `xxhash` does not seem to have such a method.  How would I be able to checksum large file (3GB+) using xxhash?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the README the `xxh64_stream` method accepts an IO object, so you can do

```
File.open("some_file") do |f|
  XXhash.xxh32_stream(f,12345678)
end
```